# Migrating Gmail to Office 365

Tags: active-directory, migration, g-suite, gmail, microsoft-office-365

I have been setting up Office 365 for my organization. We are currently using Gmail. I have synced our local Active Directory server w/ Office 365, as well as our domains. The problem I am having has to do with migrating mailboxes from Gmail to Office 365.

I have been using this article to walk me through the process: [Migrate from Gmail to Office 365 in 7 steps.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568114.aspx)

The issue arises when I begin to sync the mailboxes. Currently I have been trying to sync my own mailbox as a test. The synchronization process has been going on for about 15 hours (for just one mailbox) with no errors or any information given by Office 365, other than the "Syncing" status on the migration page in the Exchange Admin Center.

Is syncing a single mailbox supposed to take this long, or have I missed a step?

Comment: How big is the mailbox, and how much upstream bandwidth does your site have?

Comment: Bandwidth on your site shouldn't matter at all, because mail contents are pulled by Office 365 from Gmail servers via IMAP.

Comment: The mailbox itself is 1gig

Comment: You do know you get free support with Office 365, right?  Why not raise a ticket and work through it with MS?

Comment: you're probably throttled.
Google has IMAP limitations.
See <http://kb.cloudiway.com/google-throttling-limitations/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this doesn't look really good as an answer and I apologize in advance... but it happened to me exactly this way: for unknown reasons, sometimes an IMAP migration might just get stuck and not proceed at all. Try canceling it and starting it again.

Sadly, I'm no kidding here: when it happened to me, I even opened a support call with Microsoft. After two days of useless efforts, it just "magically" started working *with the same settings*, and nobody was able to explain why it hadn't worked before.

No rant intendeed, but sometimes Office 365 is just *that* reliable.

Comment: sadly, I would have to agree that this might be the best next step to try. O365 is still a little wonky at times and they (microsoft) are making changes to the backend it seems almost weekly affecting migrations on the front end.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That seems reasonable to assume it's some sort of connection issue between Office and Gmail. How long did it take you to migrate your inboxes when it WAS working?

Comment: I was not migrating from GMail, but from an internal mail server, which was constrained by local bandwidth and old hardware; I have no useful metric for how much a GMail migration should take. Anyway, if the migration *is* happening, you should see some progress update (number of synced items, etc.) in the migration job details; if there isn't any, then the job is very likely stuck.